# How to remove/add more than one class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider and when I click on nav buttons, I want to put the class "active" on one element and "active2" on another one. Here's the code I have... It's not working. It works on first slide, which leads me to believe the class is not being added to other slide on click.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('input[name="slider"]').click(function(event){
           $('.top').removeClass('active');
           $('.bkg').removeClass('active2');
           $('.slider-wrapper').find('div').eq($(this).index()).find('.top').addClass('active');
           $('.slider-wrapper').find('div').eq($(this).index()).find('.bkg').addClass('active2');

       });
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <input checked type=radio name="slider" id="slide1" />
  <input type=radio name="slider" id="slide2" />

  <div class="slider-wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
      <section>

<div class="top active">
            <img src="images/test.png">

        </div>
        <div class="bkg">
           <a class="active2">hello</a>
                    <img class="bkg-image" src="images/test.jpg">
        <div class="overlay"></div>

        </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="top">
      <img src="images/test.png">
    </div>
    <div class="bkg">
      <a class="active2">hello</a>
        <img class="bkg-image" src="images/test.jpg">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
  </section>

  </div>
  <!-- .inner -->
</div>
<!-- .slider-wrapper -->
<div class="slider-dot-control">
  <label for=slide1></label>
  <label for=slide2></label>

</div>

</div>
</article>
```

Comment: we probably need to see your html too - do you have multiple inputs with name="slider"? if not the `$(this).index()` call might not be working

Comment: please post your html code too

Comment: Okay added HTML

Answer (score 0):

The `find('div')` was finding all divs under slider-wrapper, not just the top level ones.  That resulted in the later chained selectors to not work the way you wanted.

If you switch the find to .top and .bkg then the `eq` selector seems to work as intended.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('input[name="slider"]').click(function(event){
           $('.top').removeClass('active');
           $('.bkg').removeClass('active2');
           $('.slider-wrapper').find('.top').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
           $('.slider-wrapper').find('.bkg').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active2');           
       });
    });
```